# Question involving the following Discrete Probability Distribution: $P(M = n) = \frac{6}{\pi^2 n^2}, n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I thought of a scenario with a discrete probability distribution with infinite support that puzzled me quite a bit.

Consider a button that gives you a random amount of money, \$$M$, that follows this distribution:

$$ P(M = n) = \frac{6}{\pi^2 n^2}, n \in \mathbb{Z}^+ $$

You are allowed to press the button any number of times, however it will cost you $100 to press the button each time.

With the goal of making profit, should you ever press the button?

We can calculate the expected profit as such:
$$E(M-100) = \left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nP(M = n)\right) - 100$$

However the summation yields,
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nP(M = n) = \frac{6}{\pi^2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$$

which diverges. It's apparent that with  an infinite amount of money, you should always press the button, as the expected profit is infinite. However, it feels unintuitive to say that with only $100 that you should. And in fact, you incur a loss 99.39% of the time if you do press the button.

Question: What is the amount of money that you should have, that would allow you to be more likely to make a profit than a loss from pressing the button multiple times (i.e. $P(\mathrm{profit}) > 0.5$)?

Comment: This is a variant of the St. Petersburg paradox: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox

Comment: Also, it's unclear what you mean by "would allow you to make a profit." Do you mean, does there exist a strategy that is guaranteed to make you profit (which is impossible since with positive probability you lose all your money)? Or that there exists a strategy that has positive expected value (playing a single time would suffice)? Or something else?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks for the link! That's fair, my wording in the question is unclear. I meant to ask at what finite amount of money would allow the probability of profit to be greater than that of loss. I will edit the question to ask $P(\mathrm{profit}) > 0.5$. Thank you!